# Passing special characters like '+' (plus) from Angular to Express.js not working

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I have a web app with angular front end running on Angular 4.3.6 with express.js handling routing at the back end.
I am trying to query from angular using

```
getStuff(name: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>('/someroute', {
        params: new HttpParams().set('name', name)
    });
}
```

Now this `name` variable can contain something like `ABC+XYZ`, a string actually present in the server. This code actually sends this to the backend
`/someroute?name=ABC+XYZ`

My express code is set up like

```
router.get('/someroute', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query.name)
}
```

`console.log()` outputs `ABC XYZ`. Express is converting the + as a space.

I tried Url Encoding the `name` parameter in angular like

`params: new HttpParams().set('name', encodeURIComponent(name))`

But this causes Angular to convert `%2B`(code for `+`) to `%252B`(`%25` is code for `%`).

Also, according to my title, I will need a solution for other special characters too. I know how to do this in a hacky way but I am looking for a non hacky solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar situation and after much frustration I've realized that using string interpolation and replace works.

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('name', name);

getStuff(name: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(`/someroute/?${params.toString().replace(/\+/g, '%2B')}`);
}
```

If you were attempting to do this with characters used in Query Parameters (like '=' or '&') you could probably build the url and it's parameters manually instead of using HttpParams:

```
getStuff(name: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(`/someroute/?someValue=${myValue.replace(/\+/g, '%2B')}&anotherValue=${anotherVal}`);
}
```